# Android Studio: "cannot resolve symbol R" after importing Project from Github and rebuilding/cleaning/syncing with gradle files

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I imported a project from github ("https://github.com/londonappbrewery/I-Am-Poor-Android") and my Main class cannot resolve the symbol R. I googled and tried the following solutions:

- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Sync Project with gradle files

I am new to Android Studio and currently following a tutorial on Udemy. If somebody could help me understand why it is not working and helping to find a solution, I would be very thankful!

Comment: Make sure you are using Android Studio 3.3.1, as this project uses the 3.3.1 release of Android Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brotherrrrrr, your project uses the 3.3.1 release of the Android Gradle plugin.
Make sure you are using Android Studio 3.3.1 aswell.

Greetings,

Your brotherrrrr